# Django Query set to fetch a data from a database?

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates, django-views

I have created a Model as given bellow:

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals

from django.db import models


class TypesOfVehicle(models.Model):

    type = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.type


class vehicleDetails (models.Model):

    T = models.ForeignKey(TypesOfVehicle)
    NoOfWhl = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    year = models.CharField(max_length=4)
    ModelName = models.CharField(max_length=254)
    VID = models.CharField(max_length=254, verbose_name="VID")
```

To View the above data I have written down a view as follows:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from .models import CountryDiseases, Country


def VData(request):
    Count = vehicleDetails.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'DATAPLO/MAP.html', {'Count': Count })
```

and to render the view of i have write down a simple template like this

MAP.html

```
{% for c  in Count %}
{{c.NoOfWhl }} {{ c.year }} {{ c.ModelName }}<br/>
{% endfor %}
```

My Question is that I'm very novice for Django, After few unsuccessful attempts I am not able to write down a method which can render my data as given bellow.

How can I modified the view and template section so that it could return something like this

Sample Input data:

```
NoOfwhl year modelName VID Type 

4       2014 xyz111    786 SUV
2       2012 445444    789 bk
4       2014 655656    676 car
3       2013 565656    459 tax
4       2010 565656    567 SUV
3       2019 345353    359 tax
3       2013 234224    789 tax
4       2014 L34535    345 SUV
3       2011 456464    789 tax
3       2012 456465    799 tax
4       2033 345353    09u car
2       2014 354354    454 scl
```

Now lets suppose if some one click on "SUV" it should return all the information associated with "SUV" as given bellow:

urls key as "SUV":

```
NoOfwhl year modelName VID 

4       2014 xyz111    786 
4       2010 565656    567 
4       2014 L34535    345
```

Comment: If my answer solved your problem, can you accept it ? ;)

Answer (score 6):

I tried to understand your question and I will answer with an example from my Django web application.

In my case, but yours is similar, I have a template which renders all companies from my database in a table. I display all companies and if I click in a cell, I can consult a new template with all informations according to this company. It's exactly the same issue that you asking for.

**First step : urls.py file**

In this file, I have 3 urls according to your issue :

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^Formulaire/Societes$', views.Identity_Societe_Form, name = "SocieteFormulaire"),
    url(r'^Resume/Societes$', views.Identity_Societe_Resume, name = "SocieteResume"),
    url(r'^Contrat/Societe/(?P<id>\d+)/$', views.Identity_Contrat, name="Contrat"),
]
```

- `SocieteFormulaire` lets to fill the form and save the object in my database
- `SocieteResume` lets to display all companies in a table with multiple informations. In this table, I can click inside in order to display the company template.
- `Contrat` lets to display a template in function of the choosen company

Second step : view.py file with Resume function

In my view, I have a function which let to display all companies inside an HTML Template.

```
@login_required
def Identity_Societe_Resume(request) :

    societe = Societe.objects.all()
    contrat = SocieteContrat.objects.all()

    paginator = Paginator(societe, 10)
    page = request.GET.get('page', 1)

    try:
        societe = paginator.page(page)
    except PageNotAnInteger:
        societe = paginator.page(1)
    except EmptyPage:
        societe = paginator.page(paginator.num_pages)

    paginator = Paginator(contrat, 10)
    page = request.GET.get('page', 1)

    try:
        contrat = paginator.page(page)
    except PageNotAnInteger:
        contrat = paginator.page(1)
    except EmptyPage:
        contrat = paginator.page(paginator.num_pages)

    context={
        "societe" : societe,
        "PageNotAnInteger":PageNotAnInteger,
        "contrat" : contrat,
    }

    return render(request, 'Identity_Societe_Resume.html', context)
```

I display all companies registered in my database in this html template named : `Identity_Societe_Resume.html`

The core of this template looks like :

```
<h4><b> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span></span> Récapitulatif des Sociétés ayant souscrit à un contrat de services : </b></h4>
            <table style="width:125%">
                <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <th>ID</th>
                    <th>Nom</th>
                    <th>État</th>
                    <th>SIRET</th>
                    <th>SIREN</th>
                    <th>NAF-APE</th>
                    <th>Adresse</th>
                    <th>Ville</th>
                    <th>Pays</th>
                </tr>
                {% for item in societe %}
                <tr>
                    <td><a href="http://localhost:8000/Identity/Contrat/Societe/{{item.id}}"> Ici </a></td>
                    <td>{{ item.Nom}}</td>
                    <td>{{ item.Etat}}</td>
                    <td>{{ item.SIRET }}</td>
                    <td>{{ item.SIREN }}</td>
                    <td>{{ item.NAF_APE }}</td>
                    <td>{{ item.Adresse }}</td>
                    <td>{{ item.Ville}}</td>
                    <td>{{ item.Pays.name }}</td>
                </tr>
                {% endfor %}
                </tbody>
            </table>
```

As you can see, my table displays some informations and displays the `company ID`. But this information is a link to the company template according to the `urls.py` file shown previously.

Third step : views.py file with company informations

In this step, I display informations according to the good company.
In my url, I have : `http://localhost:8000/Identity.Contrat/Societe/1`

Number `1` displays informations about `company 1`

Then I have in my view :

```
@login_required
def Identity_Contrat(request, id) :

        societe = get_object_or_404(Societe, pk=id)
        contrat = get_object_or_404(SocieteContrat, pk=id)
        #etc ...
```

It's really important to have : `(request, id)` and in each queryset I referred about `company ID`

Finally, in my template I have :

```
<h4><b> Récapitulatif concernant la société : {{societe.Nom}}</b></h4>
            <table style="width:125%">
                <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <th>ID</th>
                    <th>Nom</th>
                    <th>État</th>
                    <th>SIRET</th>
                    <th>SIREN</th>
                    <th>NAF-APE</th>
                    <th>Adresse</th>
                    <th>Ville</th>
                    <th>Pays</th>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>{{societe.id}}</td>
                    <td>{{ societe.Nom}}</td>
                    <td>{{ societe.Etat}}</td>
                    <td>{{ societe.SIRET }}</td>
                    <td>{{ societe.SIREN }}</td>
                    <td>{{ societe.NAF_APE }}</td>
                    <td>{{ societe.Adresse }}</td>
                    <td>{{ societe.Ville}}</td>
                    <td>{{ societe.Pays.name }}</td>
                </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
```

Hopefully this example is helpful and I apologize about my English which is very suck ..

Comment: my god that's a big and complete answer

Comment: Thank you :) As I'm working on my project, I don't have lot of time in order to adapt my script to his question. But It's exactly what he wants from my point of view :)

Comment: Thanks for such a long answer and code, though as I am beginner, hence  I need to  fit this code as per my requirement. Will get back in hours after trying out this code. thanks

Comment: can you add few lines about "paginator = Paginator()"  in your answer or here in comment box, relevant to your code, because, after reading a lot I am not very sure what exactly "paginator" can do for us. Thanks in Advance

Comment: `paginator` lets to display table with a page process. If you have a table with 20 lines, you can set a paginator process and cut your display in 2 pages with 10 elements on each one, or 5 pages with 4 elements on each one etc .. It's necessary if you display an html table with multiple lines ;)